# Exclude folder from Windows Defender - Context Menu

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to add a right click context menu for folders where I can add that folder to the windows defender exclude list.

So far I figured this out

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\
```

Created a new Key, Called it "WindowsDefenderExclude"
Set the key inside to "Exclude from Windows Defender"

Created a new key, Called "Command"
Set the key inside to

```
PowerShell.exe Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%L"
```

I got the right click menu to appear, but the command does not work. I don't know what to put at %L for the current folder path

Comment: Looking at other commands for directories I would say you need "%V"

Comment: Tried that too with no success

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Isn't it %1 for first argument? (https://superuser.com/questions/321953/windows-powershell-executing-commands-via-the-context-menu/322037#322037)